# How do I get the JSON data from ZOHO books API using PHP curl?

Tags: php, curl, zoho, zohobooks

I just want to Fetch all the contacts data with address using php curl

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/examples.html#2._Fetch_Records_from_the):

```
<?php

              header("Content-type: application/xml");
              $token="AUTHTOKEN";
              $url = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/getRecords";
              $param= "authtoken=".$token."&scope=crmapi";
              $ch = curl_init();
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
              curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $param);
              $result = curl_exec($ch);
              curl_close($ch);
              echo $result;
              return $result;

?>
```